# while loop not showing all the data gathered from database

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop, nested-loops

while loop not showing all the data gathered from database .. showing only last gathered item in the page. rather than showing all.

```
<?php 
    include "connect_to_mysql.php"; 
    $dynamicList = "";
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 6");
    $productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
    if ($productCount > 0) {

    //here is problem in this while loop.. dont know why it is not gathering all the items.


       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
         $id = $row["id"];
         $product_name = $row["p_name"];
         $price = $row["price"];
         $date_added = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["date"]));
         $details = $row["details"];
         $category = $row["category"];
         $subcategory = $row["sub_category"];
         $category2 = $row["category2"];
         $img_name = $row["img_name"];
         $v_id = $row["v_id"];
         $v_name = $row["v_name"];
         $v_number = $row["v_number"];
         $v_email = $row["v_email"];

         $dynamicList="

           <div id=\"single_product\" style=\"float:left; margin-left:20px; padding:10px;\">

           <h3> $product_name  </h3>
           <h3> <img src='pics/$img_name' width='200px' height='200px'/> </h3>
           <p><b><center> RUP $price </center></b></p>

           <a href=\"details.php\" style=\"float:left; font-size:20px;\">Details</a>
           <a href=\"cart.php\" style=\"float:right; font-size:20px;\">Add To Cart</a>

           </div>            
         ";

       }
   } else {
        $dynamicList = "We have no products listed in our store yet";
   }
   mysql_close();
?>
```

i am stucked here plz get me out me out from here

Comment: remove `LIMIT 6` from query, `LIMIT 6` means only last 6 rows

Comment: @Shehary What will that solve. Has 6 results now and only show 1 what difference will 100 results make????

Comment: @Shehary. i tried this.. still not working.

Comment: @RiggsFolly .. i didnt get you man..

Comment: check @RiggsFolly answer

Comment: @RiggsFolly but still OP has to remove the limit if wants to get all the records

Comment: We have to assume that OP only wants 6 rows. But he does want to see all 6 not just the last one

Comment: yeah i removed that limit bro.. thanx for that man. @Shehary

Comment: @Shehary I am not going to get into a `ner ner ne ner ner` session with you. Showing all could as easily have meant all of the **6** rows OP selected

Comment: @RiggsFolly ooouuucccchhhh, it hurts, didn't mean you were wrong and i was right but anyhow my apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using

```
$dynamicList="...
```

In your loop. I assume you are echoing the `$dynamicList` later in the code. You need to use text concatenation rather than just an `=`

So do

```
$dynamicList .= "...
```

and it will add to the string each time round the loop rather than overwrite it

Comment: ahh.. let me check this bro

Answer (score 0):

Try removing your:

```
 $productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
```

You're already fetching the rows in your whole loop and giving an else statement if the loop is empty. You don't necessarily have to count them.

I encountered something similar a few months back and believe that it was the same issue you are having now.

Stick the if statement inside your while loop:

```
if ($productCount > 0) {
```

Then put above the while loop:

`$productCount = 0`;

And within the while loop, before your if statement:

```
$productCount++;
```

**Edit:**

I've just noticed something else, you aren't actually echoing out your dynamic list. You're setting a variable but not displaying it?

Comment: Not actually going to solve the OP problem though is it

Comment: i tried removing that.. but still doesnot worked when i removed that

Comment: Aaaand someone's beat me to it. Anyway, happy coding.